# SwiftUI - Adding locations to data model

Tags: mapkit, swiftui

I currently have a data model that has an array of venues and I'm trying to add in location information for each venue. I'm running into a problem when I'm defining the struct. Here is an example of the data.

```
venues: [
                Venue (
                    title: "Holiday",
                    venueImage: "defaultVenue",
                    venueDesc: "ipsum lorem",
                    venueArea: "World East",
                    coordinate: .init(latitude: -33.852222, longitude: 151.210556),
                    venueItems: [
                        venueItem (
                            id: 101,
                            title: "Potato Dumpling",
                            itemURL: "default.png",
                            productDescription: "Potato Dumpling with Mushroom Sauce",
                            productPrice: 4.50,
                            productType: "Food",
                            newStatus: false,
                            diningPlan: false,
                            kidFriendly: true,
                            vegetarian: false,
                            glutenFree: false,
                            featuredProduct: false,
                            containsAlcohol: false
                        )])]
```

And here is the struct

```
struct Venue: Identifiable {

let id = UUID()
let title : String
let venueImage: String
let venueDesc : String
let venueArea: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
let venueItems: [venueItem]

init(title: String,
     venueImage: String,
     venueDesc: String,
     venueArea: String,
     coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
     venueItems: Array<Any>) {
    self.title = title
    self.venueDesc = venueDesc
    self.venueArea = venueArea
    **self.venueItems = [venueItem]**
    self.coordinate = coordinate

}


}
```

The error I'm getting is: Cannot assign value of type '[venueItem].Type' to type '[venueItem]'

Answer (score 0):

```
struct VenueItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var itemURL: String
    var productDescription: String
    var productPrice: Float
    var productType: String
    var newStatus: Bool
    var diningPlan: Bool
    var kidFriendly: Bool
    var vegetarian: Bool
    var glutenFree: Bool
    var featuredProduct: Bool
    var containsAlcohol: Bool
}

struct Venue: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var venueImage: String
    var venueDesc: String
    var venueArea: String
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var venueItems: [VenueItem]
}

let venues = [
    Venue(
        title: "Holiday",
        venueImage: "defaultVenue",
        venueDesc: "ipsum lorem",
        venueArea: "World East",
        coordinate: .init(latitude: -33.852222, longitude: 151.210556),
        venueItems: [
            VenueItem(
                title: "Potato Dumpling",
                itemURL: "default.png",
                productDescription: "Potato Dumpling with Mushroom Sauce",
                productPrice: 4.50,
                productType: "Food",
                newStatus: false,
                diningPlan: false,
                kidFriendly: true,
                vegetarian: false,
                glutenFree: false,
                featuredProduct: false,
                containsAlcohol: false
            )
        ]
    )
]
```